# Callback function after animating list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback, fadein

I have an animation fading in (fadeIn()) List Items in an unordered list. I have that much working, but I want to call another function after the list items are all visible - I am guessing this would be a callback function.

Basically, after my 6 list items are faded in I want to fade in a border between them. That's it! Just having trouble with the placement of the callback function, I keep getting errors where I think the function should go.

Thanks in advance for any HELP

**HTML code :**

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>interior</li>
      <li>exterior</li>
      <li>apartments</li>
      <li>homes</li>
      <li>garages</li>
      <li>rooms</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**Javascript code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentItem = null;
    var speed = 1000; //Speed of animation
    var gap = 700; //The delay between each list item fadeIn

    function showItemBorders() {

        $('ul li').css('border-left', 'border-left:1px solid #333').fadeIn('slow');

    } //My function that should be used as a callback when list items are finished

    function doNext() {
        if(currentItem==null) {
            currentItem = $('ul li:first'); //Get the first List Item
        }
        else if(currentItem.next().length!=0) {
            currentItem = currentItem.next();
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            currentItem.fadeIn(speed, doNext);
        }, gap);
    }

    doNext();

});
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5sXyq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
if($('ul li:last').is(':visible')) {
   showItemBorders();
}else if(currentItem==null){
    // your code
}else if(currentItem.next().length!=0){
   // your code
}
```

An alternative would be fading them all in at the same time:

```
$('ul li').fadeIn(speed, showItemBorders());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your `showItemBorders` function in the `else` condition and return this function in order to stop the timeout :

```
    if (currentItem == null) {
        currentItem = $('ul li:first'); //Get the first List Item
    } else if (currentItem.next().length != 0) {
        currentItem = currentItem.next();
    } else {
        showItemBorders();
        return;
    }
```

See this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8WVVp/